# Can't open ePub in Book "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory" report

Tags: books, epub

I have a bunch of ePub files a friend of mine gave me, but some of them won't load into Books (3.2). I'm running macOS Big Sur 11.6.1

The warning "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory" appear when I try to double click the "bad" files or drop it directly into Books.

[image]

Any idea why / How can I fix this ?

Comment: First I would check the epub file to see if they are correct. The first tool for all ebook stuff is [calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/download) Add the book into it then try edit - there is a option Tools->Check Book

Comment: ty @mmmmmm calibre fix the wrongs one !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @mmmmmm I was able to correct the files with [calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/download) !

After adding the book inside calibre, I went to **Edit book**

[image]

Then **Check book** (the bug icon)

[image]

And finnaly **Try to correct all fixable errors automatically**

I had 48 errors on the book, and afterward only 36 warning but it was fine for Books.app

---

I also found out that I could open the ePub on my iPhone by sending it on my email, and then it appear on both my mac and my iPhone via icloud synch